# hadoop connection refused on port 9000

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

I want to setup a hadoop-cluster in pseudo-distributed mode for development. Trying to start the hadoop cluster fails due to refused connection on port 9000.

These are my configs (pretty standard):

**site-core.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>~/hacking/hd-data/tmp</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.checkpoint.dir</name>
    <value>~/hacking/hd-data/snn</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>~/hacking/hd-data/nn</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>~/hacking/hd-data/dn</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.permissions.supergroup</name>
    <value>hadoop</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**haddop-env.sh** - here I changed the config to IPv4 mode only (see last line):

```
# Set Hadoop-specific environment variables here.

# The only required environment variable is JAVA_HOME.  All others are
# optional.  When running a distributed configuration it is best to
# set JAVA_HOME in this file, so that it is correctly defined on
# remote nodes.

# The java implementation to use.  Required.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

# Extra Java CLASSPATH elements.  Optional.
# export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=

# The maximum amount of heap to use, in MB. Default is 1000.
# export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=2000

# Extra Java runtime options.  Empty by default.
# export HADOOP_OPTS=-server

# Command specific options appended to HADOOP_OPTS when specified
export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_BALANCER_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_BALANCER_OPTS"
export HADOOP_JOBTRACKER_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_JOBTRACKER_OPTS"
# export HADOOP_TASKTRACKER_OPTS=
# The following applies to multiple commands (fs, dfs, fsck, distcp etc)
# export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS

# Extra ssh options.  Empty by default.
# export HADOOP_SSH_OPTS="-o ConnectTimeout=1 -o SendEnv=HADOOP_CONF_DIR"

# Where log files are stored.  $HADOOP_HOME/logs by default.
# export HADOOP_LOG_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/logs

# File naming remote slave hosts.  $HADOOP_HOME/conf/slaves by default.
# export HADOOP_SLAVES=${HADOOP_HOME}/conf/slaves

# host:path where hadoop code should be rsync'd from.  Unset by default.
# export HADOOP_MASTER=master:/home/$USER/src/hadoop

# Seconds to sleep between slave commands.  Unset by default.  This
# can be useful in large clusters, where, e.g., slave rsyncs can
# otherwise arrive faster than the master can service them.
# export HADOOP_SLAVE_SLEEP=0.1

# The directory where pid files are stored. /tmp by default.
# export HADOOP_PID_DIR=/var/hadoop/pids

# A string representing this instance of hadoop. $USER by default.
# export HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=$USER

# The scheduling priority for daemon processes.  See 'man nice'.
# export HADOOP_NICENESS=10

# Disabling IPv6 for HADOOP
export HADOOP_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

**/etc/hosts:**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost   zaphod

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

But at the beginning after calling `./start-dfs.sh` following lines are in the log files:

**hadoop-pschmidt-datanode-zaphod.log**

```
2013-08-19 21:21:59,430 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = zaphod/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.20.204.0
STARTUP_MSG:   build = git://hrt8n35.cc1.ygridcore.net/ on branch branch-0.20-security-204 -r 65e258bf0813ac2b15bb4c954660eaf9e8fba141; compiled by 'hortonow' on Thu Aug 25 23:25:52 UTC 2011
************************************************************/
2013-08-19 21:22:03,950 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-08-19 21:22:04,052 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-08-19 21:22:04,064 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-08-19 21:22:04,065 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
2013-08-19 21:22:07,054 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-08-19 21:22:07,060 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-08-19 21:22:08,709 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 0 time(s).
2013-08-19 21:22:09,710 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 1 time(s).
2013-08-19 21:22:10,711 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 2 time(s).
2013-08-19 21:22:11,712 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 3 time(s).
2013-08-19 21:22:12,712 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 4 time(s).
2013-08-19 21:22:13,713 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 5 time(s).
2013-08-19 21:22:14,714 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 6 time(s).
2013-08-19 21:22:15,714 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 7 time(s).
2013-08-19 21:22:16,715 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 8 time(s).
2013-08-19 21:22:17,716 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 9 time(s).
2013-08-19 21:22:17,717 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC: Server at localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 not available yet, Zzzzz...
```

**hadoop-pschmidt-namenode-zaphod.log**

```
2013-08-19 21:21:59,443 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = zaphod/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.20.204.0
STARTUP_MSG:   build = git://hrt8n35.cc1.ygridcore.net/ on branch branch-0.20-security-204 -r 65e258bf0813ac2b15bb4c954660eaf9e8fba141; compiled by 'hortonow' on Thu Aug 25 23:25:52 UTC 2011
************************************************************/
2013-08-19 21:22:03,950 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-08-19 21:22:04,052 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-08-19 21:22:04,064 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-08-19 21:22:04,064 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2013-08-19 21:22:06,050 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-08-19 21:22:06,056 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-08-19 21:22:06,095 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2013-08-19 21:22:06,097 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source NameNode registered.
2013-08-19 21:22:06,232 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2013-08-19 21:22:06,234 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2% max memory = 17.77875 MB
2013-08-19 21:22:06,235 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
2013-08-19 21:22:06,235 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=2097152, actual=2097152
2013-08-19 21:22:06,748 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=pschmidt
2013-08-19 21:22:06,748 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=hadoop
2013-08-19 21:22:06,748 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true
2013-08-19 21:22:06,754 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
2013-08-19 21:22:06,768 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
2013-08-19 21:22:07,262 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean
2013-08-19 21:22:07,322 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
2013-08-19 21:22:07,326 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory /home/pschmidt/hacking/hadoop-0.20.204.0/~/hacking/hd-data/nn does not exist.
2013-08-19 21:22:07,329 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /home/pschmidt/hacking/hadoop-0.20.204.0/~/hacking/hd-data/nn is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:353)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:434)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1162)
2013-08-19 21:22:07,331 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /home/pschmidt/hacking/hadoop-0.20.204.0/~/hacking/hd-data/nn is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:353)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:434)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1162)

2013-08-19 21:22:07,332 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at zaphod/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

After reformatting the hdfs following output is displayed:

```
13/08/19 21:50:21 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = zaphod/127.0.0.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.20.204.0
STARTUP_MSG:   build = git://hrt8n35.cc1.ygridcore.net/ on branch branch-0.20-security-204 -r 65e258bf0813ac2b15bb4c954660eaf9e8fba141; compiled by 'hortonow' on Thu Aug 25 23:25:52 UTC 2011
************************************************************/
Re-format filesystem in ~/hacking/hd-data/nn ? (Y or N) Y
13/08/19 21:50:26 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
13/08/19 21:50:26 INFO util.GSet: 2% max memory = 17.77875 MB
13/08/19 21:50:26 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
13/08/19 21:50:26 INFO util.GSet: recommended=2097152, actual=2097152
13/08/19 21:50:27 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=pschmidt
13/08/19 21:50:27 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=hadoop
13/08/19 21:50:27 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true
13/08/19 21:50:27 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
13/08/19 21:50:27 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
13/08/19 21:50:27 INFO namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
13/08/19 21:50:27 INFO common.Storage: Image file of size 110 saved in 0 seconds.
13/08/19 21:50:28 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory ~/hacking/hd-data/nn has been successfully formatted.
13/08/19 21:50:28 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at zaphod/127.0.0.1
************************************************************/
```

Using `netstat -lpten | grep java` :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50301           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       50995       9875/java       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35471           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       51775       9639/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::2181                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       20841       2659/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::36743                :::*                    LISTEN      1000       20524       2659/java
```

Using `netstat -lpten | grep 9000` returns nothing, assuming that there is no application bound to this designated port after all.

What else can I look for to get my hdfs up and running. Don't hesitate to ask for further logs and config files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you modified your mapred-site.xml as well?

Comment: Also, do you have appropriate permissions to access Hadoop?

Comment: What is the results of `jps` command on the system?

Comment: 7211 TaskTracker
6979 JobTracker
6634 DataNode
6404 NameNode
8827 Jps
6866 SecondaryNameNode
7886 HRegionServer
2775 QuorumPeerMain

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use absolute path for this and make sure the hadoop user has permissions to access this directory:-

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>~/hacking/hd-data/dn</value>
  </property>
```

also make sure you format this path like

```
# hadoop namenode -format
```

Comment: Works for me! I think the relative path caused the problems. Hadoop seems to be somewhat fragile in some cases... Thanks!

Comment: I had the similar problem. And I did the format some time ago. The weird thing is that I found I needed to format it again today!

Answer (score 4):

Modify the core-sit.xml from

```
hdfs://localhost:9000
```

to

```
hdfs:// YOUR REAL MASTER IP ADDRESS:9000
```

e.g.

```
hdfs://192.168.111.10:9000
```

works for me!

Comment: BTW I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS / Hadoop 3.1.2
After struggling for 2 days it finally works

Answer (score 1):

The short and sweet answer is that your node service is not running. simply do

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to do the following steps:

```
hdfs namenode -format

start-all.cmd
```

Answer (score -1):

Try command.

```
telnet localhost 9000
```

If telnet command returns connection refused then 
start hadoop by:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

Then by running telnet again you can see the connection is estabilished

Comment: `telnet localhost 9000` still refuses connection.