# Hadoop 2.6.0 on OS-X Yosemite

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I'm following this [tutorial](http://amodernstory.com/2014/09/23/installing-hadoop-on-mac-osx-yosemite/) for installing hadoop on my OS-X Yosemite.
On starting the server I get the following message:

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
15/02/06 10:59:20 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0/libexec/logs/yarn-sverma-resourcemanager-Ban-1sverma-m.local.out
```

However, on running any example, I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Call From Ban-1sverma-m.local/10.177.55.82 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
```

On doing a `telnet localhost 9000`, I see:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Can anyone please tell why my server is not running ?

EDIT:
This is the log inside yarn-sverma-resourcemanager-Ban-1sverma-m.local.log :

```
2015-02-05 16:41:07,723 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting ResourceManager
STARTUP_MSG:   host = Ban-1sverma-m.local/10.177.55.82
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [] 
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.6.0
```

Comment: Check your namenode daemon logs, located in logs folder, to find out what's going on ?

Comment: Logs are attached - not much informative though

Comment: Could you check both `.out` or `.log` files for the daemons. Also, have you tried running `jps` to see which processes are running and which are not ?

Comment: Yes, jps shows only ResourceManager. Also, there's nothing much in .out file

Comment: So, you don't have any HDFS related daemons running ? In that case check the NameNode logs and see if it shows any info.

Comment: I have only these log files:
yarn-sverma-resourcemanager-Ban-1sverma-m.local.log, yarn-sverma-resourcemanager-Ban-1sverma-m.local.out.1, yarn-sverma-resourcemanager-Ban-1sverma-m.local.out.3, yarn-sverma-resourcemanager-Ban-1sverma-m.local.out.5,
yarn-sverma-resourcemanager-Ban-1sverma-m.local.out, yarn-sverma-resourcemanager-Ban-1sverma-m.local.out.2, yarn-sverma-resourcemanager-Ban-1sverma-m.local.out.4

Comment: you can find an answer [here][1] Hope that this can help you 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322102/hadoop-connection-refused-on-port-9000

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually start the services and check the log files.

I have seen Connection Refused messages when the config files contain an external hostname or IP address, but the clients attempt to connect to the localhost, which resolves to the loopback address.  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618242/fs-defaultfs-only-listens-to-localhosts-port-8020) might help.